# How to model this branched sculpture?

Tags: modeling, workflow, sculpting

How can the following artwork be modeled in blender? Are there any technique to ease out the workflow.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You could definitely use Dynamic Topology (Dyntopo) and get something like that with the Snake Hook brush.

Start with a primitive like a cube or sphere.
Switch to Sculpt Mode.
Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to toggle on Dyntopo or enable it in: *Tool Shelf* > *Tools* > *Dyntopo*.

[image: sketching with the Snake Hook brush]

If you decide to use Dynamic Topology then there is no need to use a Multiresolution Modifier. As you sculpt, topology will be created or tessellated dynamically where it is needed.
Begin roughing in your shapes with a high Detail size (Maximum Edge Length) and then gradually work towards a smaller Detail pixel setting (Zooming in and out also affects detail size). The hotkey for the Detail size is <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>.
In the *Detail Refine* Method, choose *Subdivide Collapse* method when using the Snake Hook Brush. Make sure to lower your Detail so that the extrusion doesn't break apart.

Retopology will need to be performed after using this method. Note: Dyntopo will destroy custom data layers such as UVs or Vertex colors attached to the mesh. Also, anytime that you leave sculpt mode (going into Edit Mode for example) will turn off Dyntopo.

Consider the following workflow:

1. Dyntopo to create the base model
2. Retopologize mesh
3. Multiresolution Modifier Sculpting in incremental levels to add in final detail to the mesh.

Comment: i've never tried sculpting. How can one get started from basic. Are there any nice tuts on youtube?

Comment: Start here: http://cgcookie.com/blender/2013/04/29/intro-dynamic-topology-sculpting-blender/ Blender Cookie has more free and paid tutorials and of course YouTube, Vimeo and general searches on the internet will surely lead you to find other free tutorials on Blender Sculpting. Digital Tutors also has some paid courses on it.

Comment: Note that zooming in only affects detail size using relative detail setting, if you use constant detail it is fixed by the detail slider.